# Persistent BottomSheet: Swipe to Expand Issue

Tags: android, processing, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet, material-components

I've got a `CoordinatorLayout`, including a `LinearLayout` as my BottomSheet. There is also a `FrameLayout` (direct child of the CoordinatorLayout as well).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/sketchViewGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_top"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBottomSheetBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottomSheetPeekHeight"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottomSheetPeekHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/fixedPointsSeekBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:max="10"
            android:progress="10" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I use the **Processing.jar** libraries to draw stuff on the `FrameLayout`.

In order to do this I created a Fragment (so called PFragement in Processing) and added it to the FrameLayout via the SupportFragmentManager. The PFragment takes a PApplet as a constructor. In the PApplet the canvas drawing takes place and also the **width** and the **height** get defined. Furthermore I sized the PApplet to fill my FrameLayout.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val sketch = Sketch();

        sketchViewGroup.post {
            sketch.sketchWidth = sketchViewGroup.width 
            sketch.sketchHeight = sketchViewGroup.height
            // this works:
            // sketch.sketchWidth = sketchViewGroup.width -1
            // sketch.sketchHeight = sketchViewGroup.height -1 
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(sketchViewGroup.id, PFragment(sketch)).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Sketch extends PApplet {

    int sketchWidth = 100;
    int sketchHeight = 100;

    public void settings() {
        size(sketchWidth, sketchHeight);
    }

    public void setup(){
        background(0);
    }
}
```

**Now, wired things are happening:** When I size the Sketch to exactly the size of my FrameLayout my BottomSheet does not expand properly anymore. But if I subtract one of the size of my sketch everything works as expected. Can someone explain this and tell how to fix this?

```
sketch.sketchWidth = sketchViewGroup.width 
sketch.sketchHeight = sketchViewGroup.height
```

[image]

```
sketch.sketchWidth = sketchViewGroup.width -1
sketch.sketchHeight = sketchViewGroup.height -1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the height of your view group is `MATCH_PARENT` which is `-1`. When you subtract 1 from that you get `-2` which equals `WRAP_CONTENT`. So I think you are just setting the height of the sketch object to be `WRAP_CONTENT`?